# Extract pictures from tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I use the Standard Twitter API to extract pictures from tweets. For this, I use the construct

```
$utimeline = $ connection-> get ("statuses / user_timeline", ["screen_name" => "$ _GET [q]", "count" => COUNT_TWITTS]); 
$ utimeline = json_decode (json_encode ($ utimeline), TRUE);
```

from twitteroauth library for php.

If the picture is in `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/`, then it is in the subarrays of the `$ utimeline` array. And if the picture is in `https://pbs.twimg.com/ad_img/`, then it is not in any subarray.

By the way, direct parsing tweets on php gives a similar result.

Question: What tools of the Twitter API should I use to solve the problem of extracting pictures?

If you examine requests using the Network tab of the Chrome debugging tool, it turns out that the address of the desired image comes in response to such a request http://prntscr.com/qdi89n. Moreover, 22903812 is the ID of the user who posted the tweet. But to reach this address, even if you send headers like these http://prntscr.com/qdiaav, it is not possible. By the way, there is nothing in the Twitter API documentation about https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/profile/, although, for example,
https://ads-api.twitter.com/6/accounts/:account_id/cards/image_app_download info is available.